# is angulars reloadOnSearch evil?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I've been programming with angularjs for some time now, however, i started using reloadOnSearch for my application and at first i thought this was going to save me for uneccesary reloads of controllers and ajax calls against my API.

For example say i have a list of things, and then present them in a view. When you first access this view it fetches the list of items from the API and presents them, and when you click on an item it adds the `?id=xxx&view=show` query parameter to the url without reloading the controller.

When we access a single item from the already loaded list, it just fetches the list item from that we already have and presents it. However, if we forcibly reload the page, the controller now realizes that it has to fetch it from the API instead as it doesn't exist within the list collection.

At first this seemed like a great thing. However as i think about it, i now have to manage the state of the entire controller, whereas before i could have state enclosed within single functions in the controller.

I seem to be having trouble deciding if reloadOnSearch is evil and should be avoided, or if it is worth keeping around. What is your opinion?

Also, would it be better to use something like ui-router instead? I just saw a introduction video which implies that one can have better control of state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've converted my app to use ui-router instead. which basically nests application logic in "sub scopes" making it possible to share data between states/pages. I realize now that this is possible without ui-router aswell, however one would have to create pages that has a hierarchy of `<div ng-controller>`

So in conclusion, the way i was using reloadOnSearch was indeed evil. However, there were better ways of using it aswell.